# Character Overflow™ on "Edit question" button in review on mobile devices

Tags: bug, review, post-notices, responsive-design

When browsing to a review queue item for a question that has been closed on a mobile device, the new "Edit question" button in the notice overflows the word "question" as:

> Edit
> questio
> n

See screenshot below:

> [image: Edit\nquestio\nn]

Reproduced on Chrome for Android 83 on Android 10 on a Google Pixel 3a XL.